# 32-bit fixed instruction length in 64-bit memory space

Tags: arm, instruction-set

I am currently reading up on the AArch64 architecture by ARM. They are using a RISC-like instruction set with a fixed instruction length of 32-bit while operating on 64-bit addresses. I am still new to the topic of ISA so my question is: how can you operate with 64-bit long addresses when you only have 32-bit length in your instructions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

32-bit is the length of an instruction in bytes, not the operand-size or the address size.

ARM 32-bit (like all other 32-bit RISCs that use 32-bit fixed-width instruction words) can't fit a 32-bit address as an immediate into a single instruction either: there'd be no room for an opcode to say what instruction it is.

The width of an instruction limits the *number* of registers you can have.  With 3 registers per instruction (dst, src1, src2), AArch64's increase from 16 to 32 registers means that each instruction needs `3 * log2(32) = 3* 5` = 15 bits to encode the registers.  Or fewer for instructions with only 2 or 1 registers.  (e.g. mov-immediate or add-immediate).  The rest of the space goes to number of possible opcodes, and the size of immediates.

---

To get an address into a register, ARM compilers will typically load it from a nearby pool of constants (with a PC-relative addressing mode).

The other option is what most RISC CPUs do: use a 2-instruction sequence to put a 16-bit immediate in the upper half of a register, then OR a 16-bit immediate into the low half.  (Or use the lower half of a static address as the displacement to a load/store instruction that uses an addressing mode like register + 16-bit offset.)

MIPS is a good example of a very simple RISC, see [it's ISA with binary encoding](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html).  Its `lui reg, imm16` puts `imm16 <<16` into a register.  (Load Upper Immediate).  Then `lw dst, imm16(base_reg)` is a load like I was talking about in the last paragraph.

Even in 64-bit code, most numbers are still small, so there's not much need for wider immediate operands (except for addresses).  e.g. x86 still uses a choice of 32-bit or 8-bit immediate operands for `add r64, imm`.  x86 being a variable length ISA saves space when immediates are between `-128` and `+127` in a lot of cases.

Comment: Okay, so in the second part you talk about the principle of displacement? (http://web.eng.fiu.edu/watsonh/EEL4709/PresentsSu11/Group4Chapt11.pptx)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a 4-bit CPU that operates on 4096 bit values, it just wouldn't be terribly fast at doing it. Any programming language with a ["bignum" type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) will work this way, though usually not to the same extreme.

The way a 32-bit CPU can operate on 64-bit values is because the hardware or software allows it, no other reason.

It's not like we couldn't manipulate 64-bit integer values before we had 64-bit CPUs. Even the old [Intel 80386](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80386) could support 64-bit operations and it was released in 1985.

Comment: Are you talking about x87 `fild` of a 64-bit integer?  Other than using x87 or MMX/SSE2, 32-bit x86 can only do 64-bit integers with extended precision stuff like add/adc.  (Using half as many operations for add/sub as 16-bit code, though).  Producing a 64-bit full result from a 32x32 multiply doesn't quite count as a 64-bit operation, IMO, but it does make 64x64 => 64bit multiply *much* more efficient than for a 16-bit CPU.

Comment: It might be ugly, it might be inefficient, but it can be done. 64-bit CPUs just handle it a lot better, but some more modern 32-bit CPUs have 64-bit math instructions since `long long` type values are more prevalent these days than in the 1980s. Even modern 64-bit CPUs often manipulate values in excess of 64-bits: SIMD manipulates 256-bit values and floating point can easily be 80-bits. The size of the instructions, the instruction set, or the default register size has little to do with it.